# AWS S3 Access Policy - Restricting Folder Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble with AWS S3 Policies.

Essentially I have a bucket for Client Backups. I'm now automating them and have set up users for each client.

I want each client to have access to their own folder for uploading backups within the main bucket. But I don't want them to have access to other clients. I am struggling to get any policy I find to do this.

This is access via WINSCP S3 and using a Wordpress backup plugin. Not sure if this relates to anything or not.

Is anyone able to guide or help with this? I've tried multiple templates with no success. Could someone give me something?

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","CLIENTNAME/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["CLIENTNAME/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/CLIENTNAME/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you meany by users and access? IAM users? What kind of access? Listing other folders in console?

Comment: IAM users. I want them to be able to access and write to their main client folder and any sub folders. The backups are split into DEV and LIVE.

I am testing access WINSCP using the S3 option. Not via the web console.

Comment: What's wrong with your current policy? You haven't explained why it does not work, does it produce any errors?

Comment: I get access denied all the time.

Comment: You need to be very specific. Accessed denied for what? What exactly are you doing? What commands are you using?

Comment: I get access denied to even list the buckets. I am using WINSCP - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/s3

No commands, just trying to get access using WINSCP - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3#connecting

Comment: @geekcohen This sounds like an excellent use-case for [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html). One policy can grant access to folders that are based on the name of IAM Users. BTW, you typically shouldn't use IAM Users for non-staff, but it's probably fine if it is just a handful of users.

Answer (score 1):

Please approach this a bit differently.
You want to create a group and programatically add desired users to that group.
Then you want to create a custom role with your desired permissions.
Then you attach the role to the group once. And then rest your automation will take care.